# Raycast hits wrong object/block

Tags: java, raycasting

A few days ago I started a minecraft-like game in Java with jogl. But I have problems when I try to get the block the player is looking at: The raycast always hits the wrong block.

Here is my code:
I first create a direction vector from the yaw/pitch variables of the camera/player:

```
Vector3 direction = convert(player.getYaw(), player.getPitch());
Vector3D origin = new Vector3D(player.getX(), player.getY(), player.getZ());
```

To convert yaw/pitch to an direction vector I use this method: convert(float yaw, float pitch)

```
    double x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pitch)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(yaw));
    double y = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(pitch));
    double z = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(pitch)) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(yaw));

    return new Vector3D(x, y, z).normalize();
```

And this is my raycasting code

```
// The pointer resembles the current position of the raycast
    Vector3D pointer = start.clone();

    int range = 16;
    for(int i = 0; i < range; i++) {

        // Add the direction vector to the pointer
        pointer.add(direction);

        Block block = world.getBlock((int)pointer.getX(), (int)pointer.getY(), (int)pointer.getZ());
        if(block != null) {

            hitBlock = block;
            break;

        }

    }
```

Here is a screenshot that shows the wrong selection:

[image]

I also tried getting a list of all near blocks and then testing if the ray intersects the boundingbox of the cube. But that resulted in some blocks being selected because the raycast hit an face of the block that wasn't even visible to the camera.

Comment: How do you know the problem's not in `world.getBlock`?

Comment: Because every other feature (that uses world.getBlock) works perfectly fine. It basically just iterates through all blocks in the chunk and returns the block instance if it found something.

Comment: Have you attempted basic debugging techniques? What are the X, Y and Z values your code is trying for each of the iterations of the loop? What is the expected location of the block?

Comment: Before you step through with a debugger, you could try rendering the cast ray. But if that doesn't reveal any bugs, then you'll really just need to step through line by line with a debugger and watch what happens to each variable.